# Analog of MySQL like function

Tags: php, function

Suppose it's a nub question, but is there an analog of MySQL's LIKE function in PHP?

So, e.g.

```
like('goo*','google.com');//is true
like('*gl*','google.com');//true
like('google.com','google.com')//also true
```

I know regex rullez, but don't know any solution to reach this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at the [`fnmatch`](http://www.php.net/fnmatch) function.

Comment: Before 5.3, this only works on Linux (probably not a problem, just FYI.)

Comment: @notJim, thanks for the rectification, though it's not really a problem :)

Answer (score 9):

For the first, use `strpos`:

```
like('goo*','google.com');      -->  strpos('goo','google.com') === 0
```

The next one, you can use `strpos`:

```
like('*gl*','google.com');      -->  strpos('gl', 'google.com') !== false;
```

The next you can just use equals:

```
like('google.com','google.com') -->  'google.com' == 'google.com'
```

Of course, you can use regex for all of them:

```
like('goo*','google.com');      -->  preg_match('#^goo.*$#','google.com') 
like('*gl*','google.com');      -->  preg_match('#^.*gl.*$#', 'google.com');
like('google.com','google.com') -->  preg_match('#^google\.com$#', 'google.com')
```

---

**Edit**: to convert your patterns to regex, place a `^` at the beginning, and a `$` at the end, then replace `*` with `.*` and escape `.`s.

Answer (score 3):

all of those scenarios can be accomplished with [strpos](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

Comment: Thanks, i just don't wanna make another wheel:)

Answer (score 0):

In case the strings you want to match are actually files in a directory, check out the `glob` function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php

Comment: That's not even close to the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that `glob()` is specific to files in a directory, not arbitrary strings.  I have edited the answer to clarify.